# Exit from Artoo

Tags: ruby, robotics

I am using the artoo gem. I have the following code to interact with my keyboard:

```
require 'artoo'

connection :keyboard, adaptor: :keyboard
device :keyboard, driver: :keyboard, connection: :keyboard

work do
  on keyboard, :key => :keypress
end

def keypress(sender, key)
  puts key
  if key == 'q'
    puts "*** Exiting "
    exit
  end
end
```

When I press q I get a message that the actor crashed. I check the docs but I cannot see how I could exit from the program.